# Ec2 Metadata updgrade from imdSV1 to imdSV2 causes 403 and 401 error- kube2iam

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2

I recently updated my ec2 instances to use imdSV2 but had to rollback because of the following issue:

It looks like after i did the upgrade my init containers started failing and i saw the following in the logs:
`time="2022-01-11T14:25:01Z" level=info msg="PUT /latest/api/token (403) took 0.753220 ms" req.method=PUT req.path=/latest/api/token req.remote=XXXXX res.duration=0.75322 res.status=403 time="2022-01-11T14:25:37Z" level=error msg="Error getting instance id, got status: 401 Unauthorized"`

We are using Kube2iam for the same. Any advice what changes need to be done on the Kube2iam side to support imdSV2? Below is some info from my kube2iam daemonset:

EKS =1.21

image = "jtblin/kube2iam:0.10.9"

Comment: (a) this is not a programming question and thus belongs on one of the system administration stack exchange sites (b) if you are in EKS, there is 100% no reason to use the unsupported kube2iam versus [IRSA](https://github.com/aws/amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook#eks-walkthrough)

Comment: Thanks i have posted in server-fault. Yes this will give us an oppurtunity to use service-accounts which we are not using right now.